# Prove for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ that $n^2 | ((n + 1) ^ n) -1$

Tags: number-theory

Can anyone help me with this?  Do anyone know the expansion of $(n+1)^n$?

Comment: Did you mean "Taylor" or "binomial"?

Comment: Hint: look at the binomial expansion term associated with $n^1$...

Comment: binomial @abiessu

Comment: $(n+1)^n-1=n^n+\binom{n}{n-1}n^{n-1}+\cdots+\binom{n}{2}n^2+\binom{n}{1}n+1-1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set $m=n+1$, so $n=m-1$; you want to prove that, for $m\ge2$,
$$
(m-1)^2\mid m^{m-1}-1
$$
Since $m^{m-1}-1=(m-1)(m^{m-2}+m^{m-3}+\dots+m+1)$, you just need to show that
$$
m-1\mid m^{m-2}+m^{m-3}+\dots+m+1
$$
Now
$$
\underbrace{m^{m-2}+m^{m-3}+\dots+m}_{\text{$m-2$ terms}}
+1=(m^{m-2}-1)+(m^{m-3}-1)+\dots+(m-1)+(m-2)+1
$$

Alternative proof:
$$
(n+1)^n-1=\biggl(\,\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}n^k\biggr)-1
=\biggl(\,\sum_{k=2}^n\binom{n}{k}n^k\biggr)+\binom{n}{1}n=
n^2\biggl(\,\sum_{k=2}^n\binom{n}{k}n^{k-2}\biggr)+n^2
$$